# Problema para guardar los datos de un formulario en un Array

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un formulario y quiero pasar los datos de los input a un Array de objetos , el tema es que cuando quiero pasar los datos del input me guardan siempre el ultimo valor para todas las posiciones del array , un ejemplo del problema:
var vector=[]

Dato 1:
Nombre: pablo

Dato 2:
nombre:Daniel

Dato 4:
Nombre: Javier
// vector muestra : {nombre javier ,nombre: javier , nombre:javier}

codigo javascript:

```
var formulario=document.getElementById("form");
var addButton=document.getElementById("boton");

var baseDatos=[];


function Persona(nombre,edad,dni,profesion){
  this.nombre=nombre;
  this.edad=edad;
  this.dni=dni;
  this.profesion=profesion;
}  

function agregar(){
  baseDatos.push(miPersona); 
  alert("agregado");
}
function guardarDatos()
{
  localStorage.setItem("datos", JSON.stringify(baseDatos));
}

var nombre=document.getElementById("nombre");
var edad=document.getElementById("edad");
var dni=document.getElementById("dni");
var profesion=document.getElementById("profesion");
 miPersona=new Persona(nombre,edad,dni,profesion);
 addButton.onclick=agregar;
```

Codigo html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
       <form action="" method="" enctype="" id="form">
         <div>
       <label for="">Ingrese nombre:</label>
       <input type="text" id="nombre">
       <label for="">Ingrese Edad:</label>
       <input type="text" id="edad">
       <label for="">Ingrese profesion:</label>
       <input type="text" id="profesion">
       <label for="">Ingrese dni:</label>
       <input type="text" id="dni">
       <button type="button" id="boton" >Add</button>
      </div>
       <input type="submit">
        </form>
      <script src="../js/registro.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: lo que pasa es que estas ingresando solamente un dato en el array, si metes un dato y luego metes otro, el unico dato que va a quedar dentro es el ultimo que insertaste

Answer (score 0):

Hola yo en tu código aria 2 cambios, el primero

```
//var baseDatos=[];
window.baseDatos=[];
//OR
var baseDatos = [];
if(localStorage.getItem("datos") != undefined){
var baseDatos = JSON.paser(localStorage.getItem("datos"));
}
```

de esta manera me aseguro de que no borre los datos ya guardados.

y lo segundo seria

```
function agregar(){
var nombre=document.getElementById("nombre");
var edad=document.getElementById("edad");
var dni=document.getElementById("dni");
var profesion=document.getElementById("profesion");
var miPersona=new Persona(nombre,edad,dni,profesion);
  baseDatos.push(miPersona); 
  alert("agregado");
}
//...
addButton.onclick=agregar;
```

espero te ayude.